# Bildungssprachlicher Ausdruck für »unbeabsichtigt«

Tags: single-word-request

Nachdem ich unsicher war, ob es einen Bedeutungsunterschied zwischen *unintentional* und *unintendiert* gibt, habe ich die beiden Worte in die Duden-Suchmaschine eingegeben. Die Suche nach dem Wort *unintentional* spuckt aus, dass dieses eigentlich englisch und nicht deutsch ist. *Unintendiert* liefert überhaupt keine Treffer. Was ist also der richtige bildungssprachliche Ausdruck für *unbeabsichtigt* bzw. das Gegenteil von *intendiert?*

*Unintentional, unintendiert, nicht-intentional?*

Comment: Nicht intendiert.

Comment: _ungewollt_ und _versehentlich_ passen dann also nicht, weil sie gemeinverständlich sind?

Comment: Der Ausdruck, den du suchst, ist nicht *bildungssprachlich* sondern *ungebräuchlich* und ein peinlicher Versuch des Sprechers, Bildung vorzutäuschen.

Comment: Abhängig vom Kontext könnte "nicht vorsätzlich" oder "nicht mutwillig" passen.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Was ist an dem Wort "bildungssprachlich" zu bemängeln? Der Duden verwendet diese Registerbezeichnung ebenfalls.

Comment: @scienceponder Sind Sie sicher, dass Sie "bildungssprachlich" meinen und nicht "fachsprachlich"?

Comment: @AshwinS: Ich denke, Hubert Schölnast wollte nicht das Wort *bildungssprachlich* als solches kritisieren, sondern seine Anwendung auf diesen Fall.

Comment: Der Fall, also Kontext, ist für mich völlig unklar, so sehe ich auch keinen Anlass dazu, jemandes Bildungsstand in Frage zu stellen.

Comment: @AshwinS: Die Registerbezeichnung "bildungssprachlich" ist vollkommen in Ordnung, daran gibt es nichts auszusetzen, und sie kann auch überall dort eingesetzt werden, wo es angebracht ist. Aber bei diesem Wort ist es einfach nicht angebracht. Wer glaubt, in einem deutschsprachigen Kontext Worte wie *unintendiert* verwenden zu müssen, macht sich nur lächerlich. Zu deinem zweiten Kommentar: Ich sehe nicht, dass irgend einer der Kommentatoren irgendjemandes Bildungsstand in Frage gestellt hätte. Insbesondere hoffe ich, dass mein Kommentar nicht so verstanden wurde. Er war nämlich nicht so gemeint.

Comment: Kann @HubertSchölnast nur zustimmen: i.A. suchen Leute hier Worte, *die man versteht* - nicht das Gegenteil davon. Im englischsprachigen Bereich wird ein Text als umso "besser" angesehen, je leichter verständlich er ist. Im deutschen Sprachraum ist es eine alte (und anscheinend neu aufkommende) Unsitte, das Gegenteil anzunehmen - mit der der Schreiber durchaus Gefahr läuft, sich lächerlich zu machen.

Comment: Ich sehe zwischen "bildungssprachlich" und "fachsprachlich" bestenfalls einen Unterschied der Spezifität. Wer meint, sich an der Begrifflichkeit abarbeiten zu müssen: Bitte schön, gerne! Ich wollte damit eigentlich nur von vorneherein zum Ausdruck bringen, dass mir mit Begriffen wie ungewollt oder versehentlich nicht geholfen ist.

Comment: Ich möchte hier mal eine Flinte ins Korn werfen (oder einen Hasen in den Pfeffer brechen) für die Freiheit, Wörter nach Belieben zu wählen und die Wahl eines Wortes mit lateinischer Wurzel nicht gleich als elitär zu verteufeln. In bestimmten Leutekreisen und Lebenssituationen macht es keinen Unterschied, ob man "unbeabsichtigt" oder "nicht indentiert" sagt. Das kann mit Leuten sein, die sowieso laufend zwischen mehreren europäischen Sprachen wechseln (ja, gibt's), oder auch in einem Kontext wie einer Rede im Rathaussaal (um das vielzitierte Parlament mal auszulassen).

Answer (score 4):

Wenn man dem Duden glauben schenken darf, bedeutet "intentional" soviel wie "mit einer Intention verknüpft; zweckbestimmt; zielgerichtet". Wer also behauptet, er hätte etwas *nicht intentional* getan, würde behaupten, dabei keine (überhaupt keine) Absicht verfolgt zu haben. "unintentional" in diesem Sinne sind zum Beispiel Reflexe.

Das ist nicht das, was mit "unbeabsichtigt" normalerweise gemeint ist. Damit sollen eher Nebenfolgen entschuldigt werden, die nicht der Absicht der Handlung entsprechen. Man will nicht sagen, man hätte gar keine Absicht verfolgt; man will nur sagen, dass die Absicht, die man verfolgt hat, eine andere war.

Von den genannten Optionen dürfte "unintendiert" deshalb am besten passen. Ich persönlich würde (wenn schon) "nicht intendiert" vorziehen, weil es leichter über die Lippen kommt und nicht ganz so hölzern klingt. Es ist übrigens auch im Duden genannt; "diesen Effekt hatte ich [damit] gar nicht intendiert".

Comment: Danke! In meinem Kontext geht es genau um das Auftreten eines bestimmten Effekts. Ich bin dabei allerdings etwas unsicher, da unintendiert eben nicht im Duden zu finden ist.

Answer (score 1):

Und wie wäre es, in juristischem Kontext, mit "fahrlässig"?
Und dann wäre da noch "ungewollt", vielleicht nicht bildungssprachlich, aber auch nicht gestelzt.

Answer (score 1):

> nicht willentlich

ist ein schönes deutsches geschraubtes Synonym für *unbeabsichtigt*. Es ist auch *extrem bildungssprachlich*. Wenn du noch Einen draufsetzen willst, dekoriere deinen Satz mit ein paar vollkommen unnötigen Genitiv-Konstruktionen und du hast dich als vollendeten Sprachsnob geoutet.

Im Ernst: 
was ist an *unbeabsichtigt* so falsch, als dass man es nicht verwenden wollte?

Comment: An unbeabsichtigt ist nichts falsch, nur passt der Begriff im spezifischen Kontext meines Textes nicht, da darin Intentionalität als terminus technicus verwendet wird.

Comment: Wenn du einen Gegenbegriff zu *intentional* suchst, hättest du das deiner Frage hinzufügen sollen. Sollte es den nicht geben (es scheint so), spricht immer noch nichts gegen ein deutsches Wort.

Comment: ja, hätte ich in der frage vielleicht besser formulieren sollen ;)

Answer (score 0):

ich denke, hier ist die "bildungssprachliche" Ausdrucksweise: "ein nicht der/meiner intendierter/unbeabsichtigter Effekt" dann das passendste.

Comment: Willkommen bei GermanSE und danke für deine allererste Antwort :)
Könntest du deine Antwort noch etwas klarer formulieren und mit Beispielen ausbauen? Hier findest du die Anleitung dazu: https://german.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer